# NServiceBus - Multiple endpoints processing the same message

Tags: c#, nservicebus, azureservicebus

I have multiple endpoints (on different servers, from different companies) pointing at the same queue (I'm using "OverrideLocalAddress" method). When I send a message for this queue, I'm adding a header with the company ID.

I'd like to the correct endpoint to pick this message. I'm using Pipeline to filter the message I'm receiving (by company ID in the header), but just the first (a random) endpoint is getting the message.

Is there a way to every endpoint pick a message? Is there a better way to send the message to a specific endpoint?

Comment: You miht want to share some code or compile an MCVE (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to help others understand your problem a bit better.

Comment: Hi Pedro, we briefly had a chat earlier about this. What is it you're trying to achieve that you want this? Why can't every scaled out endpoint process the message and use multi tenancy to open a connection to a specific database?

Comment: @DennisvanderStelt Let me try to explain my scenario: I have a cloud ERP with thousands of companies. Those companies creates/updates products in the cloud and they need those products in their respective local database (to be used offline). I have a service in the companies' server with an endpoint listening to some commands in a specific queue. When I send a message/command in the ERP (with the company ID in the header), I need to the correct endpoint to get this message. I'm using Pipeline to filter the messages using the header, but just the first endpoint is getting the message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `Competing Consumer` pattern, which is a great pattern!

https://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/patterns/messaging/CompetingConsumers.html
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/patterns/competing-consumers

I'm assuming you don't need messages to arrive at a specific endpoint, you need data updated in a specific database. In other words, you need multi-tenancy, which enables you to use the same codebase to provide services to different customers while minimizing the effect they have on each other.

We recently wrote a blogpost about some new features in NServiceBus to better enable this: https://particular.net/blog/multi-tenancy-support-in-sql-persistence

You should be able to provide custom code and custom connectionstrings (to specific customer databases) to enable multi tenancy. Depending on the persister you are using, that is. We have [documentation for SQL Server](https://docs.particular.net/persistence/sql/multi-tenant) and other persisters and also samples that explain how to [inject tenant-aware components into message handlers](https://docs.particular.net/samples/multi-tenant/di/) or [propagate tenant information to downstream endpoints](https://docs.particular.net/samples/multi-tenant/propagation/).

I hope this helps.

**UPDATE**
I'm not sure this is the best solution, there might be others, but you can use `SendOptions` to route to a specific logical endpoint, [but also to a specific instance of an endpoint](https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/messaging/send-a-message?version=core_7.2#overriding-the-default-routing).

Comment: Thanks from the reply! I think this approach doesn't help me because I can't access the companies' databases from the outside. That's why I created a service that's running in the companies' server (where the database is located). 

I don't know if it's relevant, but I don't actually send the data in the message, I just send a date range to be used by the message handler to capture the data. I just need to tell the company's service that has new data to be captured.

Any other help is appreciated!

Comment: It's really best if you contact us at support@particular.net. This needs more context and maybe a conference call to make sure we're at the same page.

But if you need to send messages to a specific endpoint that is running at another location, use SendOptions: https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/messaging/send-a-message#overriding-the-default-routing